# ArcGIS Error: Could not connect to an ArcGIS license manager running on host "Not_Set"

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I followed this [guide](https://esri.uconn.edu/software/arcgis-student/download/#) to download ArcGIS and now I am getting this [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W4ZF.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a message you get when ArcGIS can not find the concurrent licence for the software.

Go into Arc Administrator and select the type of licence you are using (Concurrent or Single Use). 
If you are using a concurrent licence, under Licence Manager, type the name of the licence and click apply.

This [link](https://community.esri.com/thread/82400) has some great information.

[image: Screenshot of Arc Administrator]